# Update trackbar value on mouse wheel

Tags: c#, trackbar

I am using the scroll event but this only update value in label when i click on trackBar and move it right or left. I see that i can move it when i use mouse wheel but this doesn't update value in label just moving it.

```
private void metroTrackBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    lblVolume.Text = metroTrackBar1.Value.ToString();
}
```

So my question is:

**How I can make trackBar to update value in label when i scroll with mouse wheel?**

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, used `ValueChanged event` instead of `Scroll event`, this works in both cases, when i move trackBar with mouse wheel or when i drag it with mouse.

```
private void metroTrackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblVolume.Text = metroTrackBar1.Value.ToString();
}
```